# How to get an array from a splitted column in Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have something like this

```
posts = Post.all
posts[1].tags => "one, two, three"
posts[2].tags => "two, three, four"
posts[3].tags => "three, four, five"
```

How to get

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

Comment: You should look into a more robust tagging solution. Storing comma-separated values in the database isn't going to scale very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Post.all.map { |post| post.tags.split(', ') }.flatten.uniq
```

Or if you don't want to load entire models into memory:

```
Post.pluck(:tags).map { |tags| tags.split(', ') }.flatten.uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use collect instead of map

Post.all.collect{ |post| post.tags.split(', ') }.flatten.uniq